# Where can I find an unix man documentation website that can be integrated with omnibox search?

Tags: manpage, omnibox

Where can I find a unix man documentation website that can be integrated with omnibox search?

I want to open a man webpage when I type "man xxx" in Chrome omnibar. Now, the only thing I miss is a good man website that supports search.

Answer (score 0):

At this moment the best resource I was able to find was `https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ls`

Anyone has a better one?